# What would the perl commands be for this script?

Tags: perl, bash

I have a short bash script that finds the release ID in /etc/os-release, and prints a string based on that result. I would like to convert it to perl, if possible. I'll appreciate any help with this.

Here is the script that I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash

grep "ID=fedora" /etc/os-release > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
echo "You are running Fedora"
else
echo "You are running Ubuntu"
fi
```

Thanks, and have a great day.:)
Patrick.

Comment: Why would you want it in Perl if you apparently don't know Perl?

Comment: `sed -ne 's/^ID=/You are running /p' /etc/os-release` -> *You are running debian* ;-)

Comment: The back story for the need is this: I have an Amahi Home Server. One of the scripts changes your IP Address, and it restarts the networking service. If it were a bash script, then essentially what I put in for code above would work (altering the echo statements with the "service network/networking restart" commands). But the script is in perl. So I figured I'd give them the perl form of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would convert that to Perl. Shell script is the best way to go for such requirement.

Following `perl` script is one way of conversion

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $fedora = 0;
open my $fread "<", "/etc/os-release" or die $!;
while (<$fread>) {
    if (/ID=fedora/) {
        $fedora = 1;
        last;
    }
}
if ($fedora) {
    print "You are running Fedora\n";
} else {
    print "You are running Ubuntu\n";
}
close $fread;
```

Comment: Well ultimately it's going to be part of a larger perl script. What I need is the grep and the if then/else portions. Instead of it echoing the line, it will have system("service network restart"); for Fedora and system("service networking restart"); for Ubuntu.

Comment: The script is part of a server that only runs on Fedora or Ubuntu, so those are the only two values needed to work with.

Comment: @PatrickDickey Got you. Does above code solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Open /etc/os-release and read lines into array @list
open(F,'/etc/os-release');
my @list=<F>;
close F;

# Search for all lines containing "ID=fedora"
my @matchinglines= grep /ID=fedora/,@list;

# If the number of matching lines is >0 it's Fedora
if(scalar @matchinglines>0){
    print "You are running Fedora\n";
} else {
    print "You are running Ubuntu\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne'
  last if $f = /ID=fedora/;
  END{ print "You are running ", $f ? "Fedora":"Ubuntu" }
' /etc/os-release
```

Answer (score 0):

One way, althought not the most efficient because it reads the whole file in memory:

```
perl -MList::Util=first -e '
    printf qq|You are running %s\n|, 
        ( first { m/ID=fedora/ } <> ) ? 
            q|Fedora| 
                : 
            q|Ubuntu|
' /etc/os-release
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne 'print "You are running $1\n" if /^ID=(.+)/' /etc/os-release
```

Comment: What happens if neither `Fedora` nor `Ubuntu` appear in the file?

Comment: If there is no match for /^ID=(.+)/, then nothing is printed.

Answer (score 0):

As an old experienced kamikaze:

```
#!/bin/bash

ID="something unknown"
test -r /etc/os-release && . /etc/os-release
echo You are running "$ID"
```